# Solving a system of equations with 3 unknows

Tags: linear-algebra

```
X/Y = 5
X/Z = 2.5
Y/Z = 0.5
```

I don't want to check if this system is correct, but rather get actual values of X, Y, Z which could actually fit into this. 
From my head I can think of examples like x= 5, y = 1, z = 2 and 50, 10, 20 would work as well here.

But what would be a formula to actually get numbers which would fit as x, y, z. DOesn't matter if its 5, 1, 2 or 50, 10, 20.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your example doesn't work. Have you tried multiplying each side of each equation by something to get rid of the fractions?

Comment: Just multiply the first equation by Y and the second and third by Z to get a linear system with the same solutions as long as Y and Z are not zero. I'm assuming you now how to sole linear systems?

Comment: No, I dont. What does this give me?
X = 5Y
X = 2.5Z
Y = 0.5Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest converting your system of equations into a 3 by 4 matrix and using Gaussian elimination (google it to find out how). You find that your system has an infinite number of solutions (one for each value of z), with $y = \frac{2z}{5}$ and $x = 5y = 2z$.

Comment: Thanks. I found out what I wanted.

Comment: No probs @raimis